# Unusual behavior with the built in decode method (aiohttp is used as well)

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding, aiohttp, python-3.9

So I was trying to scrape an entire page. I expected both to work fine. So this is the code that doesn't work:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio

url = "https://unsplash.com/s/photos/dogs"

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
        async with s.get(url) as r:
            enc = str(r.get_encoding())
            bytes = await r.read() <--- returns <class 'bytes'>
            with open("stuff.html", "w") as f:
                f.write(bytes.decode(encoding=enc, errors="ignore")) <-- in errors I've tried all possible accepted values.

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

This results in an `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2713' in position 58100: character maps to <undefined>`. Which I'm assuming is a character in the stated position that for one reason or another can't be decoded and converted into a string.
By modifying the `main` function to the following, it works fine.

```
async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as s:
        async with s.get(url) as r:
            enc = str(r.get_encoding())
            bytes = await r.read()
        with open("stuf.html", "wb") as f:
            f.write(bytes)
```

I'm not sure why it won't work. Because in the second code block, I'm just writing the bytes to a file called `stuff.html` with the context manager. And in the first code block. I'm just taking a longer way of doing the same thing with the `decode()` method, to well decode it and turn it into a string to be written to a file. So I don't need to open the file with the `wb` or `w`, etc.

Comment: If you just write \u2713 to a file it doesn't matter if you can't decode it. It probably will work fine if you used the "utf-8" encoding instead of charmap.

Comment: `enc = str(r.get_encoding())` when printing `enc` it's "utf-8". Or am I not understanding what you're saying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f.write(string)` encodes a string to bytes before the actual writing using system-default encoding if the explicit encoding was not set in `open()` call.

On Windows, the filesystem encoding is `charmap` by default (see [locale.getpreferredencoding()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding)); not `utf-8`. Charmap cannot encode all utf-8 characters, that's why you see the error.

There is a discussion about switching Windows default encoding to utf-8 but the switch adds backward compatibility problems and thus not performed yet.

The current file encoding state is described in [Python Docs for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#utf-8-mode).